# Usar Funcion Round de PHP

Tags: php

Una consulta no logro que funcione com deseo la siguiente funcion:

```
<?php
    $variable= 150;

    $resultado = round($variable/100, 0)* 100; 

    echo"$resultado";
?>
```

**Quiero que mi resultado sea:**

Si el numero de la variable es entre 150 a 200 el resultado es de 200 (este funciona bien).

**Mi problema:**

Si el numero de la variable es por ejemplo 120 el resultado es de 100 (yo necesito que el resultado en este caso sea 150).

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: u en caso que la variable sea 220?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo usaría un redondeo personalizado, el cual pueda ajustar de acuerdo a mis necesidades, y el código seria el siguiente.

```
<?php
$variable= 150;
$residuo=$variable%100;
$resultado = round($variable/100, 0)* 100;  
if ($residuo>0 && $residuo<50){
    $resultado = $resultado+50;  
}
echo"$resultado";
?>
```

Comment: Si tengo una variable de menos de 50 puedo tener un resultado que sume de a 1 envez de a 50. saludos

Comment: Claro, solo cambia el 50, pero le sumarias 1 cada cuanto?

Comment: Es decir si mi variable fuese menos de 80 en este caso quisiera que sume de a 1 solamente ¿como seria posible?. muchas gracias. saludos

Comment: Disculpa, pero ahora te entendí menos, la ventaja de hacer personalizado el redondeo es que tu puedes definir rangos donde se comporte de una u otra manera, pero si vas a hacer algo tan variable como tener muchos rangos, tendriamos que hacer algo mas optimo como un switch.

Comment: ok, lo entiendo. voy a intenar realizarlo como me indica, utilizando variables. Muchas gracias por su amabilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Se podría solucionar verificando si el resultado esta entre el rango tomar 200 en caso contrario tomar 150

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $variable= 150;

    $resultado = round($variable/100, 0)* 100; 
    $resultado=($resultado>=150&&$resultado<=200)?200:150;
    echo"$resultado";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> esta es mi solución, sugiero algo personalizado también

```
$variable= 120;
$resultado2 = 0;
$resultado3 = 0; 
$resultado2 = ($variable/100)* 100;

$resultado3 = substr($resultado2,1,-1);
if($resultado3 < 5){
$resultado2 = substr($resultado2,0,-2)."50";
}else{
$resultado2 = round($variable/100, 0 )* 100;
}
echo"resultado2:".$resultado2."<br>";
```

Comment: gracias, si mi variable es 80 mi resultado no es 100, segun pude comprobar.

Answer (score 0):

> Si el numero de la variable es por ejemplo 120 el resultado es de 100 (yo necesito que el resultado en este caso sea 150).

Lo que ocurre es que la función round() en PHP, en su comportamiento por defecto, redondea hacia el vecino entero más cercano, es decir 1,2 será redondeado a 1, mientras que 1,6 será redondeado a 2.

En el ejemplo que planteas, cuando la variable es 120, al dividirla por 100 queda en 1,2 lo cual es redondeado a 1, porqué es su vecino entero más cercano, terminando en 100 después de la multiplicación.

Podrías usar algo como:

```
<?php
$tope = 150;
$valor = 120;

$resultado = (round($valor /100, 2) + (round($tope /100, 2) - round($valor /100, 2) )) * 100;

echo ($resultado);
```

¡Suerte!